# how to use select-string to get value of particular string from txt file

Tags: powershell

How do I get a specific string from txt file using `select-string` for example, what I tried so far is:

```
$path = "\\serverpath\servername.txt"
$list = select-string -path $path -pattern "node"
write-host $list
```

---

`servername.txt` contains:

```
servername is node1 and it is development server, it has problem
servername is node2 and it is production server, it is good
```

So I need to list only the words `node1`, `node2` ...from the `.txt` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use `Select-String` for this you can just expand your Pattern to match the digit following `node` and extract the matched Value like this:

```
$path = "\\serverpath\servername.txt"
$list = Select-String -Path $path -Pattern "node\d+" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches.Value}
Write-Host $list
```

**Explanation:**

`"node\d+"` -> `\d+`  matches the word `node` + x-digits after the word (x > 0)

`%` -> alias for `ForEach-Object` Value given from the Pipe

`$_.Matches.Value` -> Gives the matched Value

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the edit (I forgot the difference between `*` and `+`)! Just for clarification, is there another difference between `\d*` and `\d+` other than that the first would also match 0 numbers? If not I would put both cases in the answer with an explanation :)

Comment: above works, however, I am not getting complete result. how can I simply fetch particular word from txt file without any number/digits, for example, servername or server as word mentioned in txt file or any particular word from a txt file - thanks for the help

Comment: @Mickey If the word has no numbers or anything changing, that is - if you already know the word to search for in advance - why would you need to fetch it from the file at all?

Comment: @Paxz: If you used `*`, you'd also match strings such as `nodefoo`, which is probably undesired.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - there are over 2000 servers with random name and I do not know the server names, but all servers have standard prefix to its name, on that basis I want to fetch out servernames from a file. thanks

Comment: @MickeyThen take a look at how regex work here (https://regexr.com/) and filter for whatever you search. We showed you how to find and extract matches from the file, you should be able to handle your exact cases with a little knowledge of regex-patterns.

Comment: Regex * is 0 or more matches. Regex + is 1 or more matches. A ? Is 0 or 1 match.  Although node\d* would match "nodefoo" because it'll see node, it would only print "node" thanks to the matches command forcing that. If you have nodes with letters or numbers as names I'd do `node[a-zA-Z0-9]+` as it will go until it finds a space or anything that's not alphabet/numbers.

Comment: If it's always the 3rd word you could do an array. But that's unlikely. Code would be something like a for loop going through each line. And then splitting the line and grabbing part three. `$array = foreach($line in [system.io.file]::ReadLines("$path")){$line.split(' ')[2]}`

Comment: @RobertCotterman - I applied your suggestion with above method and it worked for me. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern and then acceess the `Matches` attribute of the resulting `select-string` object.

```
$path = "\\serverpath\servername.txt"
$list = (select-string -Path $path -pattern "(node\d)").Matches
write-host $list
```

The regex pattern matches `node` plus a single digit between `0-9` following it.

https://regex101.com/r/vg4LIz/5